# Forced to return into while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, binary-tree

I am writing a Binary Tree. On trying to delete a node that has two children, I have written a method which searches for the most left node of the right child's branch.

I am getting a strange error - before returning the value, I seem to go into the while loop again despite the conditions aren't met (the flag is false). After the while loop, it recursively calls itself and ends up with a null node, because it has gone too far into the tree.

Can someone tell why does that happen?

```
protected Key rlmost (BSTreeNode node){

    BSTreeNode leafnode = null;

    if ((node.right!=null)&&(node.left!=null)&&(flag==false)){
        flag = true; // set flag to true
        System.out.println("left node" + node.left.kvPair.key);
        rlmost(node.left);
        System.out.println();
    }

    while (flag==true){
        if (node.right != null){
        System.out.println("right node" + node.right.kvPair.key);
        rlmost(node.right);
        }

        else {
            leafnode = node; 
            System.out.println("rlmost node" + leafnode.kvPair.key);
            flag = false;
        }

    }


    return leafnode.kvPair.key;
}
```

Comment: What is flag initialized to at the beginning?

Comment: It is initialised to false

Comment: Are you getting a null pointer error at the return statement with leafnode.kvPair.key?

Comment: Yes I am.. it seems to go further into the tree despite there is no nodes there. I am not sure why, because the flag is already false.

Comment: Just as an aside, you can say while(flag) and while(!flag) instead of using flag == true and flag == false. Also, you shouldn't use a while loop in a recursive function. Put the while loop in the function that calls the recursive function if you need to - it will make things a lot less complicated for you.

Comment: thank you! great advice, I will avoid it as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is your recursion. Let's assume a really simple structure. A node with no left or right (both null).

First, leafnode is null to begin with. Given the structure we can't go into the if-block. Given the flag==false, we can't go into the while loop. So you'll get a NPE when you return.

If we make this a bit more complex, with a node with a left and right, but no grandchildren, we will get the same issue.

You'll hit the first if-block. You're recurse with flag == true, but throw way the result of the recursion to the left. On the first recursion call, you can't go into the first if-block. You'll go into the while loop, then into the else-block. leafnode gets set to a node. You'll return back to the first call (this is in the if-block). leafnode is still null at this point. Boom, NPE.

How you initialize leafnode is up to you. You should probably set it to the recursive calls for rlmost.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I have set leafnode as the one they were looking up as, and eliminating the while loop. Now i am getting errors somewhere else, not related to the recursion. Thank you!